# javascript window.location.href doesn't work with IDN-hebrew domain

Tags: javascript

Example, we have a page:

[https://www.facebook.com/חמישה-נוסעים-398064063958835/](https://www.facebook.com/%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-398064063958835/) (if you open in chrome)

https://www.facebook.com/%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-398064063958835/ (**same url** if you open in IE).

I need a javascript that will return me [https://www.facebook.com/חמישה-נוסעים-398064063958835/](https://www.facebook.com/%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-398064063958835/) url. This script I'll use only in Chrome browser.
At the moment window.location.href returns the path like IE shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)`